# How to disable address bar using PHP or JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: php, address-bar

How can I disable the address bar/url textbox in PHP or JavaScript/jQuery?
Is this possible?

Comment: Not generally anymore, for quite valid security reasons. You can request for an app to go fullscreen, though.

Comment: WHat's your reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible - it'd be a phisher's dream feature. Used to be possible in popups but long since removed from all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to disable the address bar. You can use pop up window though. Pop up window address bar cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use location.replace()
from existing page such that no new url will be loaded.

or Replace the original url with some strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. None of modern browsers support it. What could make a phisher more happy than the fact (if it would exist) that his victim can't see the address of the webpage!

> No, it's not possible - it'd be a phisher's dream feature.
>   He's absolutely correct!